# sqlAdaptor.update does Add a new row and Update an existiong row, but doesnot delete the row in Database

Tags: c#, sql

I am using a datagridview in a windows application which get data from MSSQL database. After making changes in grid like editing a row and adding a new row, I am updating the DB using **sqlAdapter.update(dataset, tableName).** Edited row and newly added row properly goes and gets stored in DB,

but if I **delete** the row in datagrid and store it in DataTable and then update using **sqlAdapter.update(dataset, tableName).**, it wont update the DB.

**Please note:** The table in the updatedDS is having the updated values before hitting the below code.

```
public bool UpdateDBwithDataSet(DataSet updatedDS, string dsName)
    {
        try
        {
            Concheck();
            //sAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery, con);

            CCDcmdBld = new SqlCommandBuilder(sAdapter);
            sAdapter.DeleteCommand = CCDcmdBld.GetDeleteCommand(true);
            sAdapter.UpdateCommand = CCDcmdBld.GetUpdateCommand(true);
            sAdapter.InsertCommand = CCDcmdBld.GetInsertCommand(true);

            if (sAdapter.Update(updatedDS, dsName) > 0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open) { con.Close(); }
        }

    }
```

Please let me know what is wrong here. (Note: it doesn't throw any exception also.)

Comment: If, before calling the Update, you insert, for debugging purpose, a call to `DataTable deletedRows = updateDS.Tables[dsName].GetChanges(DataRowState.Deleted)` did you get back a table that contains the row deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer :)

i was actually doing 
**dsWFSubItem.Tables[dtName].Rows.RemoveAt(selectedWorkflowRow);**, instead we need to do as follows    **dsWFSubItem.Tables[dtName].Rows[selectedWorkflowRow].Delete();**. Then **sqlDataAdapter.Update** method deletes it from the Database.

Comment: anyone please upvote if you feel its correct. orelse post any other better option if available.